# The best way to get song from remote database

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering what is the best way to play song without having connection network ?

Explanation :
I have an application that play some songs. I can play a song whenever I want, even if I m in a tunnel or in a place where I dont have a network connection.

What is the best way to manage it ?
Does sqlite sufficient to save a song to a binary format ?
Should I store the music in a directory and register the sound path ?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

You can store song meta-data in SQLite (like: song list, titles, authors...) but storing actual audio data in it is a bad idea. The overhead of storing BLOBs in a database is pretty big. And there is no way to play audio directly off database, so I would have to unload it all to memory or create temporary file.

I suggest you to relay on normal files located on external storage.

Comment: So prefering to store the path in db and the file in an external folder ?